# Update 5 values to sum a specific number

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set that looks as follows and should always equal to 100:

[image]

If I change one of the values, I want the value next to it to be adjusted for the total sum to still be 100. Unfortunately, my code does not update the number next above or below the number, when I change any of the numbers. Also, the sub does not return an error. Any suggestions why this would be the case?

```
    Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
        If IsNumeric(Target) Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column)) <> 100 Then

                If Target.Row > 1 Then
                    Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value + 100 - Application.Sum(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column))
                Else
                    Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value + 100 - Application.Sum(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column))
                End If

            End If
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The sub shouldn't compile.  You have an extra `End If` at the end.

Comment: I edited your question to apply consistent indenting of your code.  As @Comintern says, you have one too many `End If` statements, as evidenced by the last `End If` not being able to be indented to an appropriate level.  (Your first `If` statement is a "single-line If", and therefore should not have a `End If` associated with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. As Comintern pointed out in a comment, you have an `End If` that isn't matched to an `If`.  (You probably intended it for the single-line `If`, but single-line `If`s don't need an `End If`.)
2. You don't disable events from occurring while your code is running, which could lead to weird stuff happening when you initiate another change from your code.  (Mainly will only be an issue when first setting the values.)
3. Your `Sum` functions are only adding the numbers in rows 1 and 5.

A refactored version of your code would be as follows:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(Target) Then
        If Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column))) <> 100 Then

            If Target.Row > 1 Then
                Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value + 100 - Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column)))
            Else
                Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value + 100 - Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column)))
            End If

        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @YowE3K. Works like a charm :)